# Wordpress:Can't able to access Wordpress after migrate from http to https

Tags: wordpress, https, ssl-certificate

I am converting my wordpress site to https from http.I am using aws machine(windows OS) and i got the free ssl certificate,but when i tried to access my site it shows "**Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.**" this error message.I am tried almost all the solution(Deleting htaccess file,plugins uninstall,changing httpd.conf etc) but none of them worked.Any one help me i really need this one.

Comment: What are the permissions on your public_html file? This doesn't seem like a SSL problem but more a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to test it by removing htaccess file?
Also from your database phpmyadmin go to wp_options table and from there verify that you have https urls.

Also if it does not works then tru to rename plugins folder and then test it.

Also add Really Simple SSL plugin and test your site.

Comment: Hi,I have tried all the above things but no use.Frustrated.Help me to come out of this plz

Comment: can you tell me how you have converted this site http to https? Also from where you have bought free ssl?

Comment: brought free ssl from aws.then i am using Simple SSL plugin  to check ssl

Comment: You have to replace database urls also to https. Have you did it?  First undo your https. Then Use any database url replace plugin and replace all http with https then try to run your site using https.

Comment: I have changed all urls to http.But,actually in my site when i give http://sitename it automatically redirects to https://sitename so,in that scenario what i have to do?

Comment: Have you checked it in private window? Or Have you changed name servers of your domain?